# WMS service provides only countries boundaries and countries names without any background colors?

Tags: shapefile, wms, service-recommendations

I've tried to find a WMS service which shows:

- countries boundaries (it works like shapefile from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip)
- countries names (e.g. Germany, Poland, France,...)

But it should not contain any background colors in the countries, so it is transparent for everything, except the countries' borders and names.

If someone knows about a service which provides this WMS layer freely, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Shapefile you have will be ok, no need to find a WMS without a background.
Load the shapefile into you project (I just loaded the zip your link goes to).
I've put the Openstreet Map as a background to show that the WMS layer has no fill when finished.

[image]

In the Properties for the layer.

- Select *Symbology*
- Click '*Simple Fill*' in the top window and change '*Symbol Layer
  Type*' to '*Outline: Simple Line*'.
  [image]

[image]